# Discord JS - How to get links to connected accounts of a user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there a way in which I can retrieve the links to all the social medias and other accounts a person has connected to their discord [account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0pwj.png)?

I searched the docs to no avail and tried looking in the `user` object but I found nothing. I assume there must be some way in which I can retrieve this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible with just the code of the bot. To get the connections, you must bring the user to authorize your [application Oauth](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2). It's like adding a bot to a server, but instead of doing this the user authenticates the bot to get some information about the user.

Comment: Okay thank you! This seems like an awful lot of hassle for my niche use case. Still thank you for the help!